# UseJwtBearerAuthentication returns 404 instead of 401

Tags: c#, asp.net, jwt, asp.net-core-2.0

I want to use JwtAuthentication. I made some setups in Startup.cs class.
And set one controller to be [Authorized], but when I call that controller response is 404 not 401, why ?
When I call controller to generate me the token, it is generated successfully, but also for some reason can't used him in postman, again I'm getting error 404.
Do you have any idea why ?

```
using AutoMapper;
using Test.Core;
using Test.Persistence;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens;
using System.Text;

namespace Test
{
    public class Startup
    {

        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddAutoMapper();

            services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
            {
                options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"));
            });

            services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>(config =>
            {
                config.Password.RequireDigit = false;
                config.Password.RequiredLength = 4;
                config.Password.RequireLowercase = false;
                config.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;
                config.Password.RequireUppercase = false;
            })
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
                .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

            // ===== Add Jwt Authentication ========
            services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
        .AddJwtBearer(options =>
        {
            options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
            {
                ValidateActor = true,
                ValidateAudience = true,
                ValidateLifetime = true,
                ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                ValidIssuer = Configuration["JwtIssuer"],
                ValidAudience = Configuration["JwtAudience"],
                IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Configuration["JwtKey"]))
            };
        });

            services.AddMvc();
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            app.UseAuthentication();
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }

            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseMvc();
        }
    }
}
```

Generating Token is just private method included on loing

```
 [HttpPost]
    [ActionName("login")]
    public async Task<Object> Login([FromBody] LoginResource login)
    {
        var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(login.Email, login.Password, false, false);
        if (result.Succeeded)
        {
            var appUser = _userManager.Users.SingleOrDefault(r => r.Email == login.Email);
            return  GenerateJwtToken(login.Email, appUser);
        }
        throw new ApplicationException("INVALID_LOGIN_ATTEMPT");
    }

    private  object GenerateJwtToken(string email, IdentityUser user)
    {
        var claims = new List<Claim>
        {
            new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Sub, email),
            new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Jti, Guid.NewGuid().ToString()),
            new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, user.Id)
        };

        var key = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_configuration["JwtKey"]));
        var creds = new SigningCredentials(key, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256);
        var expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(Convert.ToDouble(_configuration["JwtExpireDays"]));

        var token = new JwtSecurityToken(
            _configuration["JwtIssuer"],
            _configuration["JwtIssuer"],
            claims,
            expires: expires,
            signingCredentials: creds
        );

        return new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(token);
    }
```

Comment: "when I call that controller response is 404 not 401", do you get redirected to any other URL? How are you calling the controller, through the browser?

Comment: Sorry it is just an API, should not redirect to anywhere.

Comment: If you browse to the controller through a browser, what happens?

Comment: It is trying to redirect to http://localhost:52656/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2Fapi%2Factivities

Comment: That's most likely what's happening when you call it from postman then. You need to generate the token at some endpoint and pass it in the Authentication header with value `Bearer TOKEN`

Comment: Yes, but if I run an API from postman, and token is not present I should get 401 as response not 404. Anyway I tried with generated token and again I'm getting 404 instead of 200 in this case. Even if my signature is valid, I checked on jwt.io

Comment: That's most likely the Identity configuration which by defaults redirects the 401 to `/Account/Login` which doesn't exist hence throwing 404. Can you post how you are creating the token?

Comment: Just update the question with that part of code.

Comment: Well, I see a typo in your security token: the second `_configuration["JwtIssuer"]` should have been `_configuration["JwtAudience"]` according to your startup

Comment: Even with that doesn't work.  Already tried, now tried once more.

Comment: You should then try until you can manually validate your token, see [here](https://www.jerriepelser.com/blog/manually-validating-rs256-jwt-dotnet/)

Answer (score 0):

Using `services.AddIdentityCore<ApplicationUser>` instead of `services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>` should solve this problem. Note that there is no overload for including a Role with AddIdentityCore:

> Role services are not added by default but can be added with AddRoles().

(^ From the [documentation for AddIdentityCore](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.identityservicecollectionextensions.addidentitycore?view=aspnetcore-5.0))

This could be implemented like this:

```
services.AddIdentityCore<ApplicationUser>(config =>
            {
                config.Password.RequireDigit = false;
                config.Password.RequiredLength = 4;
                config.Password.RequireLowercase = false;
                config.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;
                config.Password.RequireUppercase = false;
            })
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
                .AddDefaultTokenProviders()
                .AddRoles<IdentityRole>();
```